# Bootstrap (col-md-6) Fallo al alinear elementos

Tags: html, bootstrap

Estoy intentando hacer un blog por primera vez en bootstrap, pero no consigo alinear bien los elementos

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el problema que tengo, es que el texto me sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">

  <div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="https://www.indigovision.com/wp-content/uploads/management-hardware-header.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center">
      <h1>Hardware</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>Es la parte física de un ordenador, es decir la que podemos ver y tocar, en ella encontramos periféricos como ratón, teclado, pantalla, aparte de la caja del ordenador la cual esta compuesta por la fuente de alimentación, disquetes, disco duro,
        placa base (memorias RAM, ROM, CPU(UAL, UC Y UNIDAD DE REGISTRO)), procesador… </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div
```

> Nota: Para ver bien el codigo, ejecutalo en pantalla completa
>
> > **Tambien acepto alternativas a bootstrap**

Comment: Quitale la etiqueta p al div del texto, pruebalo sin nada

Comment: Lo he probado, pero no funciona.

Solo alarga el texto, pero sigue debajo de la imagen

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que estas declarando 3 divisiones de 6 columnas, la grilla de bootstrap usa 12 por lo que al poner 3 son 18, te muestra dos alineadas y la tercera la tira para abajo.
Para solucionarlo creas dos de 6, en la primera pones la imagen y adentro de la segunda el titulo mas la informacion

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">

  <div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <img src="https://www.indigovision.com/wp-content/uploads/management-hardware-header.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center">
  <h1>Hardware</h1>
  <br>
        <p>Es la parte física de un ordenador, es decir la que podemos ver y tocar, en ella encontramos periféricos como ratón, teclado, pantalla, aparte de la caja del ordenador la cual esta compuesta por la fuente de alimentación, disquetes, disco duro,
    placa base (memorias RAM, ROM, CPU(UAL, UC Y UNIDAD DE REGISTRO)), procesador… </p>
</div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

**CUANDO EJECUTES EL SNIPPET ABRILO COMO PANTALLA COMPLETA ASI LO VES BIEN**

Tene siempre en cuenta que la grilla es de 12, otras cosas que podes hacer es que al momento de que declares el tamaño de tu columna esta se puede dividir internamente en 12 otra vez ej:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid #000000;">
      Columna 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="border: 1px solid #000000;">
      Columna 2
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 1px solid #000000;">Sub Columna 1</div>
          <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 1px solid #000000;">Sub Columna 2</div>
          <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 1px solid #000000;">Sub Columna 3</div>
        </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, Gracias ;)

Answer (score 0):

He agregado una nueva fila dentro de la mitad del lado derecho que en el contenedor principal seria la mitad y le he puesto un col-md-12 al texto y titulo.

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<div class="row"> 
<div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;"> 
<div class="col-md-6"> 
<img src="https://www.indigovision.com/wp-content/uploads/management-hardware-header.jpg" alt="" width="100%"> 
</div> 
 <div class="col-md-6"> 
<div class="row>
<div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center"> 
<h1>Hardware</h1> 
</div> 
<div class="col-md-12"> 
<p>Es la parte física de un ordenador, es decir la que podemos ver y tocar, en ella encontramos periféricos como ratón, teclado, pantalla, aparte de la caja del ordenador la cual esta compuesta por la fuente de alimentación, disquetes, disco duro, placa base (memorias RAM, ROM, CPU(UAL, UC Y UNIDAD DE REGISTRO)), procesador… 
</p> 
</div> 
</div>
</div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

No toque lo demás como la fila innecesaria por si tienes algún motivo.

Comment: Funciona, pero veo mucho div, y a la hora de situarme en el codigo, me liare un poco.

Comment: En realidad los div. col-md-12 son redundantes y la primera row no esta en uso

Answer (score 0):

Prueba
    
     -->
    
    .row 
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    #columna
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="row" style="margin: 0; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="https://www.indigovision.com/wp-content/uploads/management-hardware-header.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
              </div>
              <!--crear un div para ponerlo en columna-->
            <div id="columna">
                <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center">
                    <h1>Hardware</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p>Es la parte física de un ordenador, es decir la que podemos ver y tocar, en ella encontramos periféricos como ratón, teclado, pantalla, aparte de la caja del ordenador la cual esta compuesta por la fuente de alimentación, disquetes, disco duro,
                    placa base (memorias RAM, ROM, CPU(UAL, UC Y UNIDAD DE REGISTRO)), procesador… </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: ¿solucionaste la alineación de los elementos?, cualquier otra cosa puedes comentarme, estaré encantado de contestarle.